# Circle and line construction of a compex number $z\in\mathbb C$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, field-theory

> Let $C\subseteq\mathbb C$ be the field of *constructible complex numbers*; that is, it includes only the elements $z\in\mathbb C$ which can be constructed with circles and lines.  The field $E\subseteq \mathbb R$ consists of the real and imaginary parts of all the elements $z\in C$. Prove that $C$ is the field extension of $E$ with $i$, namely, $C=E(i)$.

Well to solve this problem, I would construct a $x\in E$ with $0,1,z\in C$ and the same for $y\in E$ with $0,i,z\in C$. But I dont know how to draw that. Any suggestions?

Comment: After trying to understand your question, is this what you meant?

Comment: @Batominovski I don't think that's what he meant - makes the problem almost vacuously trivial. I think what he really meant was $E=C\cap\Bbb R$.

Comment: You can check his original text.  It mentioned the imaginary parts as well.  But I agree.  It really makes the problem trivial (that is why I was unsure about his question).

Comment: Yes, $E$ is generated by the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @Batominovski Oh, I know that what you wrote is more or less what he wrote - I believe he didn't write what he meant. With my reading there's at least something to prove: Show that the real and imaginary parts of a constructible number are constructible.

Comment: ??? If $E$ is generated by the real and imaginary parts there's nothing to prove! I can't beieve this is what the problem asked - the senseible version of the problem defines $E$ to be the real constructible numbers and then asks you to _prove_ that $E$ is generated by the real and imaginary oarts of $C$...

Comment: Maybe, what he wanted is: prove that $E=C\cap\mathbb{R}$ (which then, from your answer, leads to $E(i)=C$).  While this is easy to prove, it still requires a little work.

Comment: To put it another way: If $E$ is defined to be the real and imaginary parts of $C$ then answering the questino has nothing to do with "constucting" anything

Comment: I don't know.  Your answer is sufficient anyway.

Comment: I thougth, if I can construct from $z=x+iy$ the real and imaginary parts then I have $E$.

Comment: @Batominovski You latest conjecture regarding what the problem is is the same as mine, I think: "Define $E=A$, show $E=B$" is the same as "Define $E=B$, show $E=A$".

Comment: @serge that's what I thought you wanted to do, based on what you said in the post. _If_ that's what's required the question simply cannot be what you say it was. What you say you want to prove about $E$ is just the same as what you say the definition of $E$ is.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. My thougths were, if I can show only from $C$ there exists such an $E$ then $C=E(i)$. The question is, is $C$ the field extension of $E(i)$. It is clear, but I have to check it.

Comment: You are not making any sense. _If_ $E$ is _defined_ to be the real and imaginary parts of $C$ then showing that $C=E(i)$ has absolutely nothing to do with constructing things!

Comment: Okay, but how to proof it then? This was my idea, but when you said it doesnt make sense.

Comment: Your idea for what to do for a proof makes perfect sense, but as an answer to a different question! It's your version of the question that makes no sense, not your solution.